# Easiest color Theme format for Editor/IDE

Tags: ide, themes, wxwidgets, wxstyledtextctrl

I'm writing an programmer Editor and it is working fine except I'm reluctant to invent my own theme format. I want to have format compatible with another/other editor(s)/IDE(s) that I can download and change  a theme for my app with no change in my code at all. What Editor IDE theme format do you suggest I follow? or should I go ahead and write my own format?
I have looked at TextMate, it seems to use XML but I cannot find Docs for format
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great collection of styles right here:
http://studiostyl.es/